# cur.execute() psycopg2.ProgrammingError: can't call .execute() on named cursors more than once

Tags: postgresql, psycopg2

I'm trying to get this code to run but I get this error above. Can someone please help? I've tried reading about this in other posts but I don't really know how to apply it here. I'm trying to iterate over lines of this database and select 1400 random ones. It blocks on the error above.

```
  def paragraph_generator(test=True, itersize=5000, year=None, state=None):
        con, cur = database_connection.connect(cursor_type="server")
        cur.itersize = itersize
        while True:
            sql = f"""
                SELECT
                    text_id,
                    lccn_sn,
                    date,
                    ed,
                    seq,
                    chroniclingamerica_meta.statefp,
                    chroniclingamerica_meta.countyfp,
                    text_ocr
                FROM
                    chroniclingamerica natural join chroniclingamerica_meta
                WHERE date_part('year',date) BETWEEN 1860 AND 1920
                ORDER BY RANDOM()
                LIMIT 1400
                """
            if test:
                sql = (
                    sql + " limit 10000"
                )  # limit 1000 means it only goes through 1000 lines of the database
            else:
                pass
            print(sql)
            cur.execute(sql)
            for p in cur.fetchall():
                tokens = stem_text(p[-1])  # Stem
                # print(tokens)
                tokens = (
                    p[-1]
                    .translate(str.maketrans("", "", punct))
                    .replace("\n", " ")
                    .lower()
                    .split(" ")
                )
                tokens_3 = [
                    a for a in tokens if len(a) == 3 if a in wn_lemmas
                ]  # For 3-letter words, only keep WordNet recognized tokens
                tokens = gensim.parsing.preprocessing.remove_short_tokens(
                    tokens, minsize=4
                )  # Remove 1-, 2-, and 3-letter words
                tokens = tokens + tokens_3  # Add back in 3-letter WordNet-recognized tokens
                tokens = gensim.parsing.preprocessing.remove_stopword_tokens(
                    tokens, stopwords=stop_words
                )  # Remove stopwords in stopword list above
                print("THIS IS THE LENGTH OF TOKENS")
                a = len(tokens)
                print(a)
                if len(tokens) != 0:
                    ocr_2 = 1 - (
                        len([a for a in tokens if a in wn_lemmas]) / len(tokens)
                    )  # Generate a measure for proportion of OCR errors in a page
                else:
                    ocr_2 = float("nan")
                print("THIS IS OCR")
                print(ocr_2)
                ocr = ocr_2
                if ocr < 0.75 and ~np.isnan(
                    ocr
                ):  # If the % of OCR in a page is less than 75%, then keep the page and all tokens
                    tokens = tokens
                else:
                    tokens = []  # Otherwise, give it an empty list (i.e. drop the page)
                yield tokens
        con.close()
```

Error:

```
    cur.execute(sql)
psycopg2.ProgrammingError: can't call .execute() on named cursors more than once
```

Comment: Read this [Named/server side cursor](https://www.psycopg.org/docs/usage.html#server-side-cursors). The named cursor 'lives' on the server, you need to `cur.close()` if you want to reuse it.

Comment: thanks @AdrianKlaver! So where would I place cur.close() exactly in my code?

Comment: Assuming the issue is because you are running `paragraph_generator` multiple times I would say `cur.close()` needs to come just before `con.close()`.